# How to use chrome storage in chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I will make some chrome extension i used chrome storage, in background.js i can use chrome storage but in popup.js i can't use chrome storage

i know that i can use chrome storage in background and popup

why can't use chrome storage in popup.js?
if i print chrome.storage, i get "undefined" message

error code

[image]

chrome object log

[image]

this is manifest.json

```
{
    "author": "Teo",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "네이버웹툰보기",
    "short_name": "네보",
    "description": "네이버 웹툰을 쉽게 볼 수 있는 확장",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "version_name": "preview",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
       
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "webtoon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
        
    },

    

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "contextMenus",
        "notifications",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

popup.js

```
const weekdays = document.querySelectorAll(".divdays");
let webToonDatas = [];

function GetWebToonData(selectedWeekDay, element){
    console.log(chrome.storage); //undefind
    chrome.storage.sync.get(
        selectedWeekDay,
        function(items){
            console.log(items);
            element.ClassName = "divdays2";
            AddData(items);
        }
    )
  }

function AddData(items){
    items.forEach(element => {

    })
}

function onOpenWebtoon() {
    switch (this.innerText) {
        case "월":
            GetWebToonData("mon", this);
            AddData(webToonDatas);
            break;
        case "화":
            break;
        case "수":
            break;
        case "목":
            break;
        case "금":
            break;
        case "토":
            break;
        case "일":
            break;
    }
}

function RegisterEvent() {
    weekdays.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener("click", onOpenWebtoon);
    });
}

function init() {
    RegisterEvent();
}

init();
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="divMain">
        <div id="divMonday" class="divdays">
            월
        </div>
    
        <div id="divTuesday" class="divdays">
            화
        </div>
        
        <div id="divWednesday" class="divdays"> 
            수
        </div>
    
        <div id="divThursday" class="divdays">
            목
        </div>
    
        <div id="divFriday" class="divdays">
            금
        </div>
    
        <div id="divSaturday" class="divdays">
            토
        </div>
    
        <div id="divSunday" class="divdays">
            일
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's probably because you're debugging it. Close devtools or remove breakpoints that trigger before the first access to any `chrome` namespace.

Comment: I'm not seeing where the error is. But try logging the chrome object to check what's happening there whether storage is available. If not try refreshing your extension. UI changes take place without refresh but permissions and scripts require a refresh of the extension

Comment: i tried logging chrome object then i added picture result